# Prism nested Regions

Tags: wpf, prism

I have defined some regions as seen below in my main window which I have successfully filled with a view in each region. Now it turns out that I need to minimize all regions as one "window" to be able to maximize another "window".

I was thinking that I should create a region as a parent making all these regions children to this region to be able to control them as one "window". Is this the right approach? And how do I do that?

```
<Window>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">   
        <telerik:RadDocking x:Name="DockingControl" prismrgn:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static Common:RegionNames.MainRegion}">
            <telerik:RadSplitContainer InitialPosition="DockedLeft">
                <telerik:RadPaneGroup AutomationProperties.AutomationId="{x:Static Common:RegionNames.LeftAutoHide}" prismrgn:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static Common:RegionNames.LeftAutoHide}"/>
                <telerik:RadPaneGroup AutomationProperties.AutomationId="{x:Static Common:RegionNames.LeftRegion}" prismrgn:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static Common:RegionNames.LeftRegion}"/>
            </telerik:RadSplitContainer>

            <telerik:RadSplitContainer InitialPosition="DockedRight" Orientation="Vertical">
                <telerik:RadPaneGroup prismrgn:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static Common:RegionNames.TopRightRegion}"/>
                <telerik:RadPaneGroup prismrgn:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static Common:RegionNames.BottomRightRegion}"/>
            </telerik:RadSplitContainer>
        </telerik:RadDocking>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one answered, I ended up using the regionmanager to close the all regions

```
regionManager.Regions[regionname].Remove(view);
```

and thus the whole "window". Then I opened the new "window" also using the regionmanager

```
regionManager.RequestNavigate(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you would want to `Navigate` accross the views registered in the `MainRegion` in order to get the first `View` deactivated and the following one activated.

So your first approach was right, although the **Window** defined in the **Shell** would only declare the **Main Region** where the views that you want to navigate to would be then registered.

```
this.RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainRegion", typeof(MainView));
```

**Shell** view would look like this:

```
<Window>
    <DockPanel>
        <TabControl Name="MainRegion" cal:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

The other regions inside the main view you mentioned would be defined on the proper **MainRegion's** registered Views where they are contained. However, if you plan to navigate through different instances of the same view, you should be aware of creating scoped Region Managers for each navigated View in order to isolate the subRegions only into that view.

You can create a scoped region manager for a specified View as follows and register then the views that belong to every sub region:

```
IRegionManager scopedRegionManager = mainRegion.Add(objectView, null, 
                            true);
scopedRegionManager.Regions["TopRightRegion"].Add(subView);
```

You can find more information of **UI Composition** and **View Navigation** in the followings **Prism** guide chapters:

- [Composing the User Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921098%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx): - [Creating Multiple Instances of a Region](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921098%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx#sec42)
- [Navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430861%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)

Hope this helps.